# How to Replace Characters in a List in Python?

Tags: python

```
list = ["/x01", "/x30", "/x30", "/x53", "/x46", "/x46", "/x46", "/x30", "/x30", "/x30", "/x31", "/x46", "/x46", "/x0D"]

for x in list:
    x.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace('"','').replace(" ","").replace(",","").replace("[","")
```

This hasn't been working. Could you explain what I might be doing wrong, and tell me if there is a more effective way of getting the output:
"/x01/x30/x30/x53/x46/x46/x46/x30/x30/x30/x31/x46/x46/x0D"

Comment: As a side note, do you really have `"/x01"`, not `"\x01"`? (And, if it's the latter, do you have the four-character string with a backslash, or a single control-A?)

Comment: Thank you for noticing that! It is in fact supposed to be with the backslash "\x". The four character string using "\x01" instead of using control-A has been working for me.

Comment: Hold on a second, I think you're mixing up values and their representations again. The literal `"\x01"` is _not_ a four-character string, it's a one-character control-A. The _representation_ of that single-character string is the six characters `"\x01"`, but you can verify that the actual string is only one character by, e.g., typing `len("\x01")` in the interactive interpreter. Also, `print("\x01")` will print an invisible character, not four characters.

Comment: And that means if you just print out `''.join(list)`, So, you're going to get a 14-character string with an invisible character, then `00SFFF0001FF`, then a carriage return, not the 56-character string you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that `replace` doesn't change a string in-place, it just returns a new string. And you're ignoring that new string.

What you want is:

```
new_list = []
for x in list:
    new_list.append(x.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace('"','').replace(" ","").replace(",","").replace("[",""))
```

You can simplify that with `translate`, or use a different way of filtering out the characters like a comprehension or a `filter` call. But the result will be the same.

---

The bigger problem is that what you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. None of the elements in your list have a `[`, `]`, `"`, etc. character in them. You're probably confusing the string representation of the list with the list itself.

If you want to join the members of a list, or to produce *any* representation of the list other than the default `repr`, just explicitly `join` them. For example, this gets what you seem to want:

```
''.join(list)
```

… and this gets a different representation:

```
' and '.join(list)
```

… and this gets roughly the same thing as `repr`:

```
'[' + ', '.join(map(repr, list)) + ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.join`:

```
>>> lis = ["/x01", "/x30", "/x30", "/x53", "/x46", "/x46", "/x46", "/x30", "/x30", "/x30", "/x31", "/x46", "/x46", "/x0D"]
>>> ''.join(lis)
'/x01/x30/x30/x53/x46/x46/x46/x30/x30/x30/x31/x46/x46/x0D'
```

Looking at your code, I think you were trying to apply `str.replace` on `str` version of the list. But that would be a weird way to do this, better use `str.join`:

```
>>> str(lis)
"['/x01', '/x30', '/x30', '/x53', '/x46', '/x46', '/x46', '/x30', '/x30', '/x30', '/x31', '/x46', '/x46', '/x0D']"
```

The above string is just a representation of the list object.

```
>>> str(lis).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","").replace(",","").replace("'","")
'/x01/x30/x30/x53/x46/x46/x46/x30/x30/x30/x31/x46/x46/x0D'
```

Comment: In other words: `['a', 'b']` is not a string containing `'['` or `','`, which the original poster seemingly fails to notice.

Comment: Thank you, that is the problem I was facing. I'm pretty new to programming, so after having many times when I already had a string representation of a list at other points in the program, I forgot to do it here...

Answer (score 0):

You should use translate(None, nuke_list_string)

Two reasons:

1. replace performs a 1-to-1 substitution, each substitution results in the allocation of a new string which is then returned, resulting in a lot of overhead if you chain a bunch of replaces like you do in the example.
2. translate usually requires a 1-to-1 mapping, i.e. translate('ABC','abc') would convert the string 'a brown cow' to 'A Brown Cow'. However, if you specify **None** as the new mapping, it will remove the characters it finds.

Here's an example:

```
a = 'this is [a] string with (stuff) in {it}'
print a.translate(None, '[]{}()')
```

Produces:

```
this is a string with stuff in it
```

Comment: Thanks - the explanation of how to use translate along with everyone else pointing out my problem with not using .join() should make my code more effective.